# How can I track updates on the release of new open data sources across the world?

Tags: data-request, metadata

Is there any blog and / or link where I can get regular updates on the release of latest open data sources across world?

Comment: Related: [What are the most common ways users find out about new data sets?](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/477/what-are-the-most-common-ways-that-users-find-out-about-new-data-sets)

Comment: While it may sound stupid, you could probably get some interesting results by setting a [Google Alert](http://www.google.nl/alerts) on terms like 'open data' and 'public database'.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes, that's an helpful idea that is alos mentioned in another question about how to find open data. Following a search on Twitter for Open Data or #opendata could also be useful.

Answer (score 6):

There are two additional options here.

1. If you know of an open data portal for a country or topic you are interested in, many allow you to subscribe to their data updates or releases.
2. If you do not know that a source exists and are looking for one, several aggregator sites are referenced in a recent answer to your related questions on [international aggregators for NGO data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/258/are-there-any-international-non-governmental-data-aggregators/353#353).  Additionally, on Data.gov we track official [government open data portals](http://www.data.gov/opendatasites), and I can certainly look into creating a subscription feed there.

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://databullet.in. It's operated by Knoema/The World Bank but aggregates data releases as they occur from about two dozen different sources.

Also, I would recommend Quartz's [Atlas](http://theatlas.com) for newsworthy datasets, [Graphiq](http://graphiq.com) for even more journalistic-geared dataset releases and the social network data.world.